# Drawing line vertically in css

Tags: css

I am using css to try and draw a line vertically, I even tried using `float:left` thinking that it would be possible, but it stills draws it horizontally. What am I doing wrong here?

```css
        .process {
            margin: auto;
            max-width: 1080px;
        }


         #line {
            width: 80%;
            margin: auto;
            background: #eee;
            height: 6px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 10%;
            top: 57px;
            z-index: 1;
            border-radius: 50px;
            transition: all ease 0.9s;
        }

         #line-progress {
            content: " ";
            width: 3%;
            height: 100%;
            background: #207893;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #207893 0%, #2ea3b7 100%);
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
            border-radius: 50px;
            transition: all ease 0.9s;
        }
```

```html
<div class="process">
            <div id="line">
                <div id="line-progress"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple method of making the progress bar vertically, is to switch width properties with height properties, and switch gradient from `to right` to `to bottom`

```css
.process {
            margin: auto;
            max-width: 1080px;
        }


         #line {
            width: 6px;
            margin: auto;
            background: #eee;
            height: 80%;
            position: absolute;
            left: 10%;
            top: 57px;
            z-index: 1;
            border-radius: 50px;
            transition: all ease 0.9s;
        }

         #line-progress {
            content: " ";
            height: 3%;
            width: 100%;
            background: #207893;
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #207893 0%, #2ea3b7 100%);
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
            border-radius: 50px;
            transition: all ease 0.9s;
        }
```

```html
<div class="process">
            <div id="line">
                <div id="line-progress"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```